Uniqueness of Sum of Products in Paired-Sum-Equal Arrays
TL;DR:
I was trying to solve LeetCode 2491. While my question doesn't relate to the problem itself, it sparked a curiosity that led me to the following question:
Consider an array $A$ of unique integers with the following properties:
$A$ has an even number of elements $n$, where $n > 2$.
A can be split into $n/2$ pairs such that the sum of each pair is equal.
For example, in $[1, 3, 2, 4]$, we have $1+4 = 2+3 = 5$.
Let's define a value $P$ as the sum of products of these pairs.
For the example above, $P = (1 \cdot 4) + (2 \cdot 3) = 10$.
The question is:
Given an array A satisfying the above conditions, is the value $P$ always unique to A? In other words, can we find another array $B$, also satisfying the conditions, that produces the same value $P$?
We've verified that for small arrays like $[1, 3, 2, 4]$, $P$ seems to be unique within a reasonable range of integers. However, we haven't been able to prove or disprove this property for all possible arrays satisfying the conditions.
This problem has implications for using $P$ as a potential checksum for such arrays. Any insights, proofs, or counterexamples would be appreciated.

${1,2,7,8}$ and ${2,3,4,5}$ seem to be a counterexample.

Perfect! Good to know this is not true. Appreciate it.

There are also non-constructive proofs of the fact it's false.  For instance, if $A$ has four elements, then the three smallest elements may be freely chosen and they uniquely identify the largest element in $A$.  If the three smallest are chosen from $[1,N]$, then there are $\binom{N}{3}$ such $A$.  The largest element is less than $2N$, so $P$ is less than $N\cdot N + N\cdot 2N = 3N^2$.  Since $3N^2 < \binom{N}{3}$ for $N$ large enough (for $N>20$), there aren't enough values of $P$ to allow them to be unique to $A$.
Apparently, as given in the comments, there are counterexamples with $N=7$, so we don't need to go all the way to $N=20$, but the asymptotic analysis makes the question of whether such counterexamples exist fairly simple.
